# How can I get a ReactElement from a tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The `PanResponder` methods are passed a `ResponderSyntheticEvent` whose `nativeEvent.target` is a React tag (which is just a `Number`). This is the same tag that is returned by `findNodeHandle`.

Is there a way to get the `ReactElement` from the React tag?

**Edit:**

I can use `ReactNativeTagHandles.tagToRootNodeID[tag]` to get the "root node ID". Now how can I get a `ReactElement` from that?

Comment: have you found answer for that?

Comment: @Piotr AFAIK, it's not possible to get the `ReactElement` associated with a specific "tag".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ReactNativeComponentTree = require('ReactNativeComponentTree');

var reactInstance = ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(reactTag);
```

This is only available in versions of [facebook/react](https://github.com/facebook/react) **>= 15.0.2**

You can see `ReactNativeComponentTree` defined [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.0.2/src/renderers/native/ReactNative/ReactNativeComponentTree.js).

Comment: In my React Native projects I had to use `import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree';` to get this to work. That makes me think it's moving around and therefore we shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @hippietrail The file location doesn't make a difference if you're using the [metro-bundler](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler), because it has `@providesModule ReactNativeComponentTree` in the file header comment.