# How to associate an "onPress" event with the Button, TouchableOpacity, etc that generated it?

Tags: events, button, react-native, native-base, touchableopacity

In my React Native project using NativeBase I'd like to generate a series of `Buttons` or `TouchableOpacities`.

That means I don't want each to have a separate `onPress` handler but one shared one.

But when I look at what is passed to the `onPress` callback there doesn't seem to be any kind of ID or reference to the component that caused the press, nor can I find such a thing documented.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there another method everybody uses to achieve the same goal? Or is this actually missing functionality?

Comment: Do you want to each key can pass different argument in a same function?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri: Yes that's what I'm used to in other GUIs. I tried adding a `key` to each Button with a unique identified but that is buried within nested children of the arguments passed to my `onPress` callback so it can't be the right way.

Comment: Update your code if you can. so I can help you better.

Comment: This comes up quite often under different wordings that are seldom linked: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817758), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651770), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494965), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195606), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584585), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706257). Answers include use `bind` or arrow function inside `render`, [which is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733), or calling unstable undocumented internal functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your function as below:

```
  _onPressButton = (id) = () => {
      // do something with id
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;


  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Button onPress={this._onPressButton(item.d)}>
      ...
    </Button>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data_array}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
  );
```

Comment: No, you missed that I am **generating** the buttons, I am not declaring them manually. I will add them dynamically from an array, object, etc.

Comment: Not different you can create your Buttons dynamically and put the `onPress` method in it. if you want I can update my answer in this way.

Comment: I'll check this out and come back with votes or comments, thanks (-:

Comment: Sorry I had to un-accept this because when I went to actually try it out I couldn't get it to work with just what's here alone. I didn't get anywhere with the other answer either.

Comment: It lacks context. For instance I don't know if it's inside a normal, pure, or functional component. Maybe I'm too new to too many concepts to get by on this alone.

Comment: These are not in your question scope. if you want to know more about it you should search or open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ref` to identify a component

`<Button ref={'loginButton'} onPress={this.onButtonPress()}>`

Then you access it using `this.refs['loginButton']`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I need to use `bind` for this? In my search I've seen a lot of things with `bind` and `this` that I don't totally grok and none of them seemed to work in my case so far.